# Строптивый и не отзывчивый <li>

Tags: javascript, html, html5, события

Есть список в нем его детишки-liшки:

```css
ul {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8f93b6;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elem">
    <li id="li">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

И вот я задумал обратится к `<li>` и по клику именно на него добавлять вопросительный знак в конец его текста, а в случае клика на `<ul>` добавить новый элемент `<li>` снизу. Не сработало, хотя я писал самые вежливы обращения:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('#elem')

//Ниже варианты обращения к li
let li = ul.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)
let liID = document.getElementById('li')
let liAll = document.querySelectorAll('li')
// let liTag = document.getElementsByTagName('li') // HTMLcollection тоже самое что и liAll
// let liCh = ul.children // HTMLcollection тоже самое что и liAll



ul.addEventListener('click', foo)

function foo(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target) // <li>
  console.log("Put all <li> together version: ", ev.target === liAll );         // false при обращении к HTMLcollection
  console.log("Personal index version: ",        ev.target === liAll[0]);      // true только если кликнуть на  указанный индекс
  console.log("Personal <li id='li'> version: ", ev.target === liID);         // true только если кликнуть на указанный ID

  if (ev.target === li) { // Тут было вместо li - 'li', liAll, liID, liAll[0], 'LI'
    ev.target.innerHTML += '?'
  }
  this.append(li)
}
```

Выходит, чтобы добраться до `<li>` мне нужно каждому придать `id` и привязать событие к нему, что абсурд. Или перебрать циклом HTMLcollection(не важно каким способом добытую) и связать элементы цикла с событием `ev`, что тоже кажется не изящным.

Одно интересное, что в `ev.target` есть свойства `nodeName: "LI";` и `localName: "li"`. А значит `ev.target.localName === 'li';` или `ev.target.nodeName === 'LI';` вернет `true` и наша задумка заработает, но нет тут уникальности, что если на странице много и других `li` под другими `ul`, а мне нужны именно эти `li`.

Вопрос как добраться до всех `<li>` без цикла, без `id`, и фамильярных обращений в стиле `ev.target.localName`?
Второе почему у меня добавляется в конец `<ul>` всего один элемент `<li>`? Потом событие будто отвязывается. Хотелось бы множить их нажатиями.

Comment: Вы случайно не учитель по русскому и литературе?) Свой JS код, пожалуйста тоже вставьте в минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Думаю, что добраться до всех <li> без цикла нельзя, могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уникальный `id` для `ul` и потом смотреть, являются ли `li` дочерними. Почему один добавляется уже написали в других ответах.. Так же другие ответы работают не корректно у @rusgeli при клике на `li` добавляется элемент.. У @webDev_ если кликнули по первому `li`, затем клонируется и вставляется с уже добавленным `?`.. Без фамильярности вряд ли.. Всё таки вы работаете с вложенными элементами. Вопрос только в том, какой путь идентификации `li` выбрать..

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('#elem');

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e){    
    let elem = e.target;
    let parentId = elem.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
    if (parentId == "elem") {
      elem.innerHTML += "?"; 
    } else if (elem.getAttribute('id') == "elem") {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = 'text';
      this.append(li);
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8f93b6;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elem">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего кроме как через цикл или получение свойств события не получится никак.
Вы, на самом деле почти добились поставленной цели, только вам нужно сравнивать не `ev.target` с `li`, а `ev.target.nodeName` с `'li'`, и тогда `?` будет добавляться к нажатому элементу. Поскольку событие вы навесили на родительский `ul`, другие `ul` и `li` затронуты никак не будут (кроме вложенных, это исправляется доп проверкой  `ev.target.parentElement == ul`).

Почему добавляется только один элемент? Потому что вы пытаетесь добавить один и тот же элемент много раз (это как дважды на елку повесить один и тот же шарик). Вам необходимо создавать или клонировать элемент, а потом уже добавлять в конец.

Вот примерный вариант:

```js
    let ul = document.querySelector('#elem')

    //Ниже варианты обращения к li
    let li = ul.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)
    let liID = document.getElementById('li')
    let liAll = document.querySelectorAll('li')
    // let liTag = document.getElementsByTagName('li') // HTMLcollection тоже самое что и liAll
    // let liCh = ul.children // HTMLcollection тоже самое что и liAll



    ul.addEventListener('click', foo)

    function foo(ev) {
      console.log(ev.target) // <li>
      console.log("Put all <li> together version: ", ev.target === liAll );         // false при обращении к HTMLcollection
      console.log("Personal index version: ",        ev.target === liAll[0]);      // true только если кликнуть на  указанный индекс
      console.log("Personal <li id='li'> version: ", ev.target === liID);         // true только если кликнуть на указанный ID

      if (ev.target.nodeName === 'LI' && ev.target.parentElement == ul) { 
        ev.target.innerHTML += '?'
      }
      let li1 = document.createElement('li'); 
      li1.innerHTML = 'text'
      this.append(li1)
    }
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8f93b6;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elem">
    <li id="li">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('#elem')

function foo(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    return ev.target.innerHTML += '?'
  }
  const li = ul.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)
  this.append(li)
}

ul.addEventListener('click', foo)
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8f93b6;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elem">
    <li id="li">text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```